# Using the standard module `parsexml`, how do I parse XML through a plain stringstream or string instead of a file

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, stringstream, nim-lang

https://nim-lang.org/docs/parsexml.html

The documentation only goes over parsing from a file stringstream with `open`, but how would I do it if I just have a plain string (e.g. httpclient client.get body).

Answer (score 2):

In order to use `parsexml` with in memory strings, you have to create streams out of strings with the [streams module](https://nim-lang.org/docs/streams.html). The `parsexml` module embeds an example to read from the file, these are the lines you need to change to make it parse from a string:

```
var filename = addFileExt(paramStr(1), "html")
let buffer = readFile(filename)
var s = newStringStream(buffer)
if s == nil: quit("cannot open the file " & filename)
```

The complete example reads:

```
import os, streams, parsexml, strutils

if paramCount() < 1:
  quit("Usage: htmltitle filename[.html]")

var filename = addFileExt(paramStr(1), "html")
let buffer = readFile(filename)
var s = newStringStream(buffer)
if s == nil: quit("cannot open the file " & filename)
var x: XmlParser
open(x, s, filename)
while true:
  x.next()
  case x.kind
  of xmlElementStart:
    if cmpIgnoreCase(x.elementName, "title") == 0:
      var title = ""
      x.next()  # skip "<title>"
      while x.kind == xmlCharData:
        title.add(x.charData)
        x.next()
      if x.kind == xmlElementEnd and cmpIgnoreCase(x.elementName, "title") == 0:
        echo("Title: " & title)
        quit(0) # Success!
      else:
        echo(x.errorMsgExpected("/title"))

  of xmlEof: break # end of file reached
  else: discard # ignore other events

x.close()
quit("Could not determine title!")
```

Answer (score 1):

I've figured it out! You actually shouldn't use `parsexml`. You use `xmldom` and `xmldomparser` with the `loadXML` procedure (pass a string!).

https://www.rosettacode.org/wiki/XML/XPath#Nim

Comment: It's not like you _should not_ use `parsexml`, but dom like modules provide an easier access at the cost of having to read and parse the whole file compared to being able to use a lightweight stream and extract only the info you need.